# Mirror the preview

Tags: android-camera, android-camera-intent

```
public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean previewing = false;;

    EditText txtData;

    String stringPath = "/sdcard/samplevideo.3gp";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button buttonStartCameraPreview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startcamerapreview);
        Button buttonStopCameraPreview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopcamerapreview);

        txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        //txtData.setText("DD");

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        buttonStartCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!previewing){
                    camera = Camera.open(0);
                    if (camera != null){
                        txtData.setText("CamOk");
                        try {
                            //txtData.setText("DD");
                            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                            camera.startPreview();
                            previewing = true;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }else txtData.setText("null");
                }
            }});

        buttonStopCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(camera != null && previewing){
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.release();
                    camera = null;

                    previewing = false;
                }
            }});

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_camera, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I am trying to preview the image using a front-facing camera. But the preview is mirrored. How can I mirror it again so that i can preview a non-mirrored preview. Please help, I have been searching this for days

Comment: Will you be satisfied with an OpenGL based solution?

Comment: i dont know about OpenGL...bt if it solve the problem i would like to learn it...For a curiosity is it not possible with the given code

Comment: @AlexCohn also i wanna make sure that this flips the live preview and not the image

Comment: I guess that OpenGL is really an overshoot. See the answer that uses a simple SurfaceTexture.